# Choose Directory from combobox and list subdirectories in textedits

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I am trying to list all subdirectories which are inside a directory(which is chosen from combobox). Now I can show list of directories in combobox . I want to select one of those directory and list every sub-dirs( inside this selected dir) in textedit.
I don't know how can I list the subdirectories when I choose a directory from combobox.Here is my current code.

```
QDir directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open  Directory"),"/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly| QFileDialog::
DontResolveSymlinks);

ui->comboBox->setMinimumWidth(500);
QStringList files = directory.entryList(QDir::Files);
ui->comboBox->addItems(files);
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: use the currentTextChanged signal that returns the selected item, after that you implement your logic with the QTextEdit

Comment: use `connect(ui->comboBox, &QCombobox::currentTextChanged, ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::append);`

Comment: How can I list subdirectories from a chosen directory?I mean in" ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::append)" how can I get the dir from combobox to list sub-dirs. The signal and slot that u mention above is right . But since I am a beginner ,can U show me some references?

Comment: According to what I see, QComboBox has filenames, not directories. On the other hand whether or not it is a beginner the best reference is the documentation and the other second is SO, do not you think someone already wondered how to get the subdirectories of a given directory with Qt? 
the next question does something similar to what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052460/recursively-iterate-over-all-the-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in, so the solution should be given by the QDir class or the QDirIterator class, check some methods there.

Comment: I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer .

```
void Combo_box::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QDir directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),"/home",
                                                       QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly| QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);

    ui->comboBox->setMinimumWidth(500);
    for(const QFileInfo & finfo: directory.entryInfoList()){
        ui->comboBox->addItem(finfo.absoluteFilePath());
    }

    connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged,[this](const QString &selectedDirectory) {
        QDirIterator it(selectedDirectory,QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

        ui->textEdit->clear();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            ui->textEdit->append(it.next());
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Make the connection outside the for-loop

Comment: OK. I can do it.But I am confused that what is the difference between putting connection inside loop and outside loop?\

Comment: the connection does not verify if the signal was ever connected to the slot, so in your case you would call the n-times lambda function.

Comment: Ah Ah Ah , how stupid i am , that is the basic logic . Thanks Thanks. :)